# Android layout draft

Tags: layout, draw, wireframe, mockups, mockup-tool

Is there programs or web apps available to draw a draft of each layout from an app prior to developing it ?

I'm not looking for something that will generate the xml layout but just a simple tool to draw a sketch for each window of my app

Comment: http://designmodo.com/android-kits-developers/

Comment: Try searching Wireframe desing tool  or use this link http://webdesignledger.com/tools/13-super-useful-ui-wireframe-tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about `mockup` and `wire-framing` tools.
There are quite a few of varying price and quality, here's a few:

- [mockupbuilder](http://mockupbuilder.com/)
- [framebox](http://framebox.org/)
- [lumzy](http://www.lumzy.com/)

I can't vouche for any of these, but they should provide what you're looking for, although pen and paper will probably outmatch them easily! ;)